# How can i modify error messages?

Tags: android, message, alert, playback

I have developed live stream app but some time the live stream is unavailable and "Can't play this video" alert message is displayed . Now i want to modify this message to another indicate  that there are problems on live stream . How can i modify it ??

Comment: So, you want to change the alert message? From what to what? More info please.

Comment: I want to change it from "Can't play this video" to "live stream is unavailable".

Comment: the question is how can i access default messages and change it ??

Comment: Other than either looking in strings.xml or in the layout file containing the text?

Comment: nothing in strings.xml. I think it is buit-in